# How to make sure mongoose save callback is run before it disconnects when parsing csv?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

New to node and can't seem to get past this. Trying to parse each row from a csv and save it into the db with mongoose.

```
csv.fromPath("tests.csv", { objectMode: true, headers: true, ignoreEmpty: true})
.on("data", function(data){
    var test = new Test(data);
    test.save(function(err, test) {
        if(err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(test);
        console.log(test.name + ' saved!');
   });
})
.on("end", function(){
  mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

The console.log's won't work because mongoose disconnects before those callbacks are run:

```
{ [MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your end handler is being called after the csv file has been parsed, but before you've saved the data to mongo. You could move the disconnect method into the save callback:

```
csv.fromPath("tests.csv", { objectMode: true, headers: true, ignoreEmpty: true})
    .on("data", function(data){ 
        var test = new Test(data); 
        test.save(function(err, test){
          if(err) return console.error(err);
          mongoose.disconnect()}); 
});
```

However, it's not the usual pattern to disconnect the mongoose connection after interacting with the database. If you have callbacks in your script, just call process.exit() in the final innermost or final one:

```
csv.fromPath("tests.csv", { objectMode: true, headers: true, ignoreEmpty: true})
    .on("data", function(data){ 
        var test = new Test(data); 
        test.save(function(err, test) { 
            if(err) console.error(err);
             process.exit();
        }); 
     });
```

I don't think calling mongoose.disconnect() will terminate your script. Oh, and don't return on error, just log the error and exit the process. If you return on error the script won't terminate either.

Comment: This is just a script I'm writing to import data. My terminal hangs if the disconnect is not explicit. How should mongoose handle it in this case?

Comment: I write  scripts like that all the time. I usually call process.exit() or is it terminate when I want to end such a script. Sorry I'm on my phone and not in front of a computer :)